# json decode not working

Tags: php, javascript

I have a data i want to `json_decode`, the data was `json_stringify` before being sent to PHP and the data looks like this:

```
{\"data\":{\"buildingID\":{\"2\":{\"path\":[[11,11],[10,11],[10,10],[9,10],[8,10],[8,9],[8,8],[8,7],[8,6]]}}}}
```

In my script i have:

```
echo $_GET['as']; //this is what you see above^
$obj = json_decode($_GET['as']);
echo $obj; //no output
var_dump($obj);  //this shows NULL
```

There are also no errors/notices/warnings in my error logs either.

I'm wondering if the slashes is causing some kind of problem ?

Comment: Are you using [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php)?

Comment: Hmm i gathered they would be off if its deprecated now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slashes are indeed the problem.

My guess is that magic quotes are the culprit.  I suggest you [disable magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Comment: Ah so it seems to be ! Thanks !